# Convert Custom Field Content to Lower Case with Dashes

Tags: add-on, custom-fields

I have a custom field with a person's name in it, and I need to convert it (in the template) to all lowercase with dashes instead of spaces so I can use it as an ID tag. Example:

`Suzie McRowdy` becomes `suzie-mcrowdy`

Is there an (ideally free) add-on that will take care of this for me?

Comment: If it's a Matrix field, you could, maybe, use the url-title FT to do the conversion.

Comment: Can you clarify if you actually want the data in the database updated *or* keep that data 'as-is' and convert on template output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to do this from the template you could use a plugin like this one:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/create-url-title

If you need to do it directly to the DB please update us so we can give you that solution as well.

Note: [CE String](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-string/user-guide/custom_methods) also has a custom method called url_title which will do the same thing but, it's not a free add-on.

Comment: Also of note, plugins can be used as formatting filters too. Check this screenshot: http://cl.ly/Tsdy You can click Edit List, enable your plugin there, and select it in the list, forcing that format on the content of your field.

Answer (score 2):

I did this with [CE String](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ce-string):

```
<a href="{url}" class="icon-{exp:ce_str:ing url_title}{label}{/exp:ce_str:ing}">{label}</a>
```

You can see the [docs here](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-string/user-guide/custom_methods#url_title)

The reason I like this method is CE String is super helpful across most site builds. It has so many useful features!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Low Replace (which is FREE!):

http://gotolow.com/addons/low-replace/docs#tags

I haven't used it for adjusting the `case` of outputted data but it is supported.

That should get you started!